# Repeated fields return AttributeError - type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'nums'

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I am following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#repeated-fields) for using protocol buffers in `python`.

Here is my `main.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto2"
message Foo {
    repeated int32 nums = 1;
}
```

I cannot access `foo.nums`.

Here is the `python` script which fails:

```
import main_pb2
foo = main_pb2.Foo
foo.nums.append(1)
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'nums'.
```

To make it even more confusing, I can see that `Foo` has an attribute called `foo.NUMS_FIELD_NUMBER`. What is going on?

Comment: The fact that the error is complaining about `type object 'Foo'` instead of `'Foo' object` is actually explaining the problem—but it’s something you’re never going to notice until the first time you’ve been burned by this and drove yourself crazy debugging it and know to look for it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
foo = main_pb2.Foo
```

should have been:

```
foo = main_pb2.Foo()
```

I wasn't calling the constructor. That fixes the error.